# Table only populating with one value from array

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, increment

I have an array from which I would like to populate table records from, unfortunately it will only populate the 1st record of the array. I anticipate I have my increments declared incorrectly, but cannot find a combination that will work. In addition I would like '$mtcelogID = $siteNAME.'.'.$Maindate.'.'.$i;' to have the last part of the ID to increment

```
$mtcelogARRAY = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(2)->rangeToArray('A8:A18');
$num_mtcelog = count($mtcelogARRAY);  // Here get total count of row in that Excel sheet
 for( $i=0; $i<=$num_mtcelog; $i++ ){
 $sql_mtcelog = "INSERT INTO `maintenance_log`(`mtcelogID`,`mtcelogTYPE`,`MaintenanceID`) VALUES (?,?,?)"; 
$query_mtcelogARRAY = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql_mtcelog);
$mtcelogID = $siteNAME.'.'.$Maindate.'.'.$i;                    
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($query_mtcelogARRAY,"sss", $mtcelogID, $mtcelogARRAY[$i][0], $MaintenanceID);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($query_mtcelogARRAY);
    mysqli_stmt_close($query_mtcelogARRAY);
}
```

The above code returns this in my PHP table:

[image]

And my array looks like this:

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you're using mysqli, but I'm going to leave this PDO answer here. If this code is a small maintenance script, there shouldn't be any trouble dumping mysqli. Notice no binding is necessary, you just pass the values as an array to `PDOStatement::execute()`. No worrying about how many `s` and `i` you have. Also, `foreach` is a much more flexible and less verbose construct than `for`.

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydatabase", $username, $password);

$mtcelogARRAY = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(2)->rangeToArray('A8:A18');

$sql_mtcelog = "INSERT INTO `maintenance_log`(`mtcelogID`,`mtcelogTYPE`,`MaintenanceID`) VALUES (?,?,?)"; 

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql_mtcelog);

foreach ($mtcelogARRAY as $i=>$arr) {
    $params = ["$siteNAME.$Maindate.$i", $arr[0], $MaintenanceID];
    $stmt->execute($params);
}
```

The important thing is to prepare your statement outside the loop. One of the main goals of prepared statements is to reduce overhead; by preparing the statement repeatedly you are increasing overhead.

Comment: Thanks for the preparation tip. I've tried this code and I still get the same results where it will only populate one row of the array. note that I've changed "$siteNAME.$Maindate.$i" to"$siteNAME.$Maindate.$id" where $id=uniqid(). I there  something else I'm missing in my prep possibly?

Comment: I would confirm your data is as expected. Also check that there aren't any problems with unique keys in the database. You can add some error checks in to make sure the preparation and execution are successful, though if it works for one it should work for all of them.

Comment: O wow I'm dense, I had MaintenanceID Indexed as unique instead on Index. TY! works great!